# How to draw a horizontal line at the SOUTH position of the BorderLayout of a Container?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a Container whose Layout is BorderLayout. I want to draw a horizontal line at the SOUTH position because this Container is drawn repeatedly so I want to delimit each by the horizontal line.

Here is the code:

```
tList = new List(tModel);
tList.setListCellRenderer(new CTable(listclient));

public class CTable extends Container implements ListCellRenderer {

  private Label pic = new Label("");
  private Container cnt;
  private Label name = new Label("");
  private Label credit = new Label("");
  private ligneHorizontal ligne;

  private Font fontLibelle = (MenuPrincipalForm.r).getFont("FontTextFieldBold");

  private Label focus = new Label("");

  public CTable(Vector valeur)
  {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, pic);
      cnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      name.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
      name.getStyle().setFont(fontLibelle);
      credit.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
      cnt.addComponent(name);
      cnt.addComponent(credit);
      ligne = new ligneHorizontal(100);
      cnt.addComponent(ligne);
      addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);
      focus.getStyle().setBgTransparency(100);
  }

  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected)
  {
      if ("-".equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(value)))
      {
          name.setText(" - ");
          credit.setText("Encours : -  Impayés : -");
          pic.setIcon(null);
      }
      else
      {
          if (index%2 == 0)
              this.setUIID("evenRowsCell");
          else
              this.setUIID("oddRowsCell");
          name.setText("123456789012 - Rasolofomanana Marc");
          credit.setText("Crédits : 15.000 (Ar) Impayés : 10.000 (Ar)");
          pic.setIcon(null);
      }
      return this;
  }
  public Component getListFocusComponent(List list)
  {
      return focus;
  }
}

public class ligneHorizontal extends Label {
    public ligneHorizontal(int l)
    {
        String t = "";
        do
        {
            t.concat(new String("-"));
        }
        while(t.length()<l);
        this.setText(t);
        this.setPreferredH(5);
        this.getStyle().setBgColor(0);
    }
}
```

And also I want to know how to coloriate even rows and odd rows of the List because I tried but the color is not get until I click on the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , I found the solution : I derived `BackgroundPainter` where in the `public void paint(Graphics g,Rectangle rect)` method I draw the line ( `g.drawLine(rect.getX(), rect.getY()+h-1, rect.getX()+w, rect.getY()+h-1);` ).
So when I want to draw a line in the container then I write `myContainer.getStyle().setBgPainter(new derivedClassName(myContainer));`

Answer (score 0):

add `Label` with preferred height 5, with black bg color between containers

Comment: That won't work because labels have a special case for empty string labels giving them a 0 preferred size value and not drawing them. The preferred width should be increased as well which might make it work although its not a great solution. We generally use repeatable images in the theme (e.g. check out the UI for the Add dialog in the T-zone Friends demo.

Comment: @Shai Almog Can you give the url of the site ?

Comment: i agree with Shai but i used to use label text `" "` (one space)